# ¿Hay un banco terminológico en español?

Tags: terminología, recursos

Hay una herramienta de traducción de euskera que a mí me resulta muy útil e interesante, lo llaman banco terminológico, aquí el enlace: [Euskalterm](http://www.euskara.euskadi.eus/q91EusTermWar/kontsultaJSP/q91aAction.do?ekin=HIZKUNTZA_ALDATU&hizkuntza=es&hizkAldatua=es). Buscas una palabra y en los resultados te aparece cómo se traduce en diferentes áreas (según aplique): informática, medicina, agricultura, etc.

Tiene más sentido en traducciones pero también podría ser que pongas una palabra y te diga en qué ámbitos se usa y qué significado tiene dependiendo del contexto. ¿Existe algo así en español, ya sea solo español o inglés-español, que sea más o menos oficial?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49604/discussion-on-question-by-blonfu-hay-un-banco-terminologico-en-espanol).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[**IATE**](http://iate.europa.eu)

- Base de datos terminológica multilingüe de la Unión Europea.
- Lenguas: las 24 de la Unión Europea

---

El propio [DRAE](http://dle.rae.es/) te indica qué acepciones pertenecen a un ámbito específico (por ejemplo, la definición de "[nudo](http://dle.rae.es/?id=QhaZAWX)" incluye acepciones en los ámbitos de la física, informática y marina, ver acepciones 13 a 17).

---

[**TERMCAT**](http://www.termcat.cat/es)

- Centro de terminología de la lengua catalana, pero que contiene información de otras muchas.
- Lenguas: catalán, español, inglés y otras.

---

[**UNTERM**](http://unterm.un.org/)

- Base de datos de terminología de la oficina de Ginebra de las Naciones Unidas.
- Lenguas: árabe, chino, español, francés, inglés y ruso.

---

[**TERMSCIENCES**](http://www.termsciences.fr/)

- Portal terminológico francés para poner en común los recursos terminológicos de los organismos públicos de investigación y enseñanza superior.
  Lenguas: francés, inglés, español y alemán.

Comment: Muy bueno! y con un montonazo de idiomas además.

Comment: ¡Espectacular el recurso del IATE, no lo conocía!

Comment: Veo alguna que otra página que lista otras opciones: [Herramientas multilingües gratuitas en línea para traductores → 1. Bases de datos terminológicas de índole general](https://traduciresdescubrir.wordpress.com/2014/10/05/herramientas-multilingues-gratuitas-en-linea-para-traductores/), un listado de la [Asociación española de terminología](http://www.aeter.org/?page_id=75) y otro de la [Red de intérpretes y traductores de la Administración Pública](http://www.ritap.es/glosateca/bases-de-datos-terminologicas/). Añadid todo aquello que consideréis útil.

Comment: Como el de TermCat, también hay TermAst que va entre castellano y asturiano (internamente, también mantienen las listas con inglés, aunque no publican las listas en él) http://www.academiadelallingua.com/termast/index.php